# Disable Screen Capture/ScreenShot in React Native App

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, screenshot

I have came across few solutions specific for ios and Android to prevent screen-capturing and taking screenshots. But how do i disable screen-capturing in react native?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### Android

Inside `/android/app/src/main/java/com/{Project_Name}/MainActivity.java`

you may add the following lines. Prevent capture screen by setFlag `FLAG_SECURE`, use code below as an example:

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
}
```

later when you want to remove secure flag

```java
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

### iOS

overlay screen in `AppDelegate.m`, take this example:

```c
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {    
    // fill screen with our own colour
    UIView *colourView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.window.frame];
    colourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    colourView.tag = 1234;
    colourView.alpha = 0;
    [self.window addSubview:colourView];
    [self.window bringSubviewToFront:colourView];
    // fade in the view
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        colourView.alpha = 1;
    }];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // grab a reference to our coloured view
    UIView *colourView = [self.window viewWithTag:1234];
    // fade away colour view from main view
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        colourView.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // remove when finished fading
        [colourView removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the iOS solution does? On my app it will just make the app fade into a white screen making the app "unscreenshottable" from background, but you are still able to screenshot within the app

Comment: How to handle this for example if go to secure message screenshot not be available otherwise should be available .

Comment: This solution only works when app is in the background.For me applicationWillResignActive is not being called when user takes screenshots

Comment: `import android.os.Bundle;` add this line on top in android

Answer (score 11):

So there is little work for the iOS side build on React Native platform. So be patient with me to read the following approach.

I am using the react-native-video package for playing media. My requirement was to show spinner if user has screen recording enabled.

1. From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/2921651-captured?language=objc I understood that `captured` property is set to YES. I added observer in AppDelegate.m, under `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

   `[[UIScreen mainScreen] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"captured" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];`
2. Since RN allows communication with Native modules, I decided to add bridge so notify when `capture` flag is set to YES.

I created two files ScreenRecordingNotification.h and .m

.h

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>
#ifndef ScreenCaptureNotification_h
#define ScreenCaptureNotification_h


@interface ScreenCaptureNotification : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>
-(void) isScreenCaptureEnabled:(BOOL)isCaptured;
@end

#endif /* ScreenCaptureNotification_h */
```

and .m looks like

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ScreenCaptureNotification.h"
#import <React/RCTLog.h>
@implementation ScreenCaptureNotification

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
  static ScreenCaptureNotification *sharedInstance = nil;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedInstance = [super allocWithZone:zone];
  });
  return sharedInstance;
}

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents {
  return @[           
           @"isScreenCaptureEnabled"];
}

-(void) isScreenCaptureEnabled:(BOOL)isCaptured {
  [self sendEventWithName:@"isScreenCaptureEnabled" body:@{@"value": @(isCaptured)}];
}

@end
```

3. import `#import "ScreenCaptureNotification.h"` in AppDelegate and added the following method.

   ```
   - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
       if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"captured"]){
         NSLog(@"Screen Capture is Enabled");
         RCTLog(@"Screen Capture is Enabled");
         if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
           ScreenCaptureNotification *manager = [ScreenCaptureNotification allocWithZone: nil];
           [manager isScreenCaptureEnabled:UIScreen.mainScreen.isCaptured];
         }
       }
   }
   ```

And also add `[[UIScreen mainScreen] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"captured" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.
This concludes changes at iOS side.

4. Now you need to add Listener in .js files for notification which iOS sending. Once you get notification, it's up to you to decide what to do with it. Roughly it will look like below.

> ```
>   addListener() {  
>     let bridge = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.ScreenCaptureNotification);
>
>     this.screenCaptureEnabled = bridge.addListener("isScreenCaptureEnabled",res => { 
>       this.setState({ screenCapture: true })
>     })
>   }
> ```

and

```
render() {
  if (this.state.screenCapture) {
     //Show spinner
     return <Spinner />
  }
  return (
  <Vido uri ... /> 
  )
}
```

I am open to suggestions to make changes to this post. Don't forget to upvote if this post helped you.

Comment: Does capture property will be true if user tries to take a screenshot?

Comment: @DhruvilShah you should give try. I tried for screen recording and its working as expected.

Comment: @Naren I tried you solution but it's not working, can you please share the code of react-native side in functional component

Comment: @vijaykahar understand this. React native and iOS can communicate using bridge. As you receive flag from iOS to React Native, you set the flag in redux which foreces app to rerender. In class file of react, you add mapStateToProps to get updated value from redux. I can't share code but if you share yours I can check that.

Comment: Showing Recent Issues
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ScreenCaptureNotification

Getting this error on Xcode 12.2

Comment: line 6 on the observeValueForKeyPath - ScreenCaptureNotification on AppDelegeate is causing the error
also, I tried to put the log inside the method it was not printing once I take a screenshot on a physical device

Comment: For a screen recording, the log was printed

Comment: Is there an official library for this now? I've tried https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/screen-capture/#preventscreencaptureasynckey but it doesn't work for iOS.

Answer (score 5):

**Prevent Capture Screen**

*Android*

Prevent capture screen by setFlag secure

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

If you want to remove flag secure

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. How about IOS?

Comment: You could have at least mention where should we put that line of code.

Comment: this answer is not clear enough, you are not stating where exactly should we insert that line of code!

Comment: @BurimSyla Look at my answer to get exact location where should put that line of code.

Answer (score 5):

In android

/android/app/src/main/java/com/{Project_Name}/MainActivity.java

write some Import Statements

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
```

Prevent capture screen by setFlag secure use below code inside the MainActivity class

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use my own custom-made library `react-native-screenguard`.

`yarn add react-native-screenguard`

`npm i --save react-native-screenguard`

Guide:

https://github.com/gbumps/react-native-screenguard/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this lines in appDelegate.m below
   *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*  when user being screen record exit app and if screen record is on app not open
   **just for ios react-native**

Answer (score 0):

screen shot false in your app
put this complete code in  your

> android/app/src/main/javacom/mainactivity/java

```
package com.Yourprojectname;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "YOUR PROJECT NAME";
  }
   
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE
  );}}
```