# How to replace screenshots by a predefined image? (With React-Native)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, image, react-native

I would like to prevent the screenshot in the mobile app (Android & IOS) this way:

- If the user do a screenshot, he finds in his photo gallery an image that I predefined instead of the screen of the application.

I can't find any information about this, if it is possible, how to do it?

I am novice, any help and simple explanation would be very appreciated.
Thank's in advance.

Comment: This is not possible on iOS. You can't prevent screenshots or alter their contents.

Comment: the close approach will prevent the user to take a screenshot using g https://stackoverflow.com/a/54998200/6181916
  and then hook save image function with screenshot event by this https://github.com/blend/react-native-screenshot-detector