# How to prevent screenshot in selected screen in android and ios react native

Tags: react-native

Previously I used this package to prevent snapshot for selected screen in android and ios.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-privacy-snapshot
https://github.com/kristiansorens/react-native-flag-secure-android

But it's not maintained by the owner and not compatible with react-native version >0.60. Many example and question in the internet only show how to prevent snapshot for whole application. But I need to prevent snapshot only for selected screen.
I've tried to do with this example

https://medium.com/@jonaskuiler/creating-a-security-screen-on-ios-and-android-in-react-native-97703092e2de

But in android, it prevents whole apps. In ios, it works.

Answer (score -1):

you can use **nmp** library, [react-native-prevent-screenshot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-prevent-screenshot)

for more confusions and a perfact understanding [check this asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54998051/disable-screen-capture-screenshot-in-react-native-app)

Comment: I also already read this package through. But it seems lack of documentation how to use it. I'm afraid it would be not maintained.

Comment: In your updated link, as I mentioned before, didn't explain how to use it in specific screen or page. It is used for whole apps

Comment: just use the fuction on the class which you want to prevent from taking screenshot