# How to prevent screenshot only when screen is on focus and disable for other screens

Tags: android, ios, react-native, screenshot, screen-recording

I want to only prevent screenshot and screen recording for certain screens like the login screen to prevent users from taking screenshot of passwords and login information and also the payment screens for the sensitive informations collected.

Most of the packages for preventing users to take screen capture usually sets it for all screens.
I have implemented the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54998051/disable-screen-capture-screenshot-in-react-native-app) but it prevented screen capture for all the screens and not for only the screen in focus.

I have also tried

```
npm i react-native-screenshot-prevent
```

same result.

Answer (score 1):

When using expo, to prevent screenshot or screen recording for single or more screens which are in focus, you can use the `useIsFocused` from `react-navigation` and the `allowScreenCaptureAsync` and `preventScreenCaptureAsync` of `expo-screen-capture`.

Below is an example as seen here https://dev.to/one/react-native-prevent-screen-capture-on-selected-screens-19f6

```
import * as ScreenCapture from 'expo-screen-capture';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function LoginScreen() {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  const activate = async () => {
    await ScreenCapture.preventScreenCaptureAsync();
  };

  const deactivate = async () => {
    await ScreenCapture.allowScreenCaptureAsync();
  };

if(isFocused){
       activate();
   }else{
       deactivate();
   }


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      ...
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this npm module, it works fine with both iOS and Android Applications

```
npm install react-native-prevent-screenshot-ios-android --save
```