# Is it possible in react-native to prevent the user from taking screenshots?

Tags: react-native

There is something similar in Java:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Is it possible to do this in react native?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Screen Capture/ScreenShot in React Native App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54998051/disable-screen-capture-screenshot-in-react-native-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You can use this `react-native-screenshot-prevent` third party library for this purpose.

```
yarn add react-native-screenshot-prevent
```

Guide:

https://github.com/killserver/react-native-screenshot-prevent